# Pass reference to require file

Tags: node.js

I have similar question to this:
[Node JS - Passing Javascript object by reference to other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905294/node-js-passing-javascript-object-by-reference-to-other-files)

The accepted answer was to require another file in each files we want to use.

For example:
file functions.js

```
exports.functionIWantToUse = function() { //code } ;
```

Other file:

```
var functionsIWantToUse = require('./functions');
```

But now if we will require those file in all other files, won't we just waste memory?
This file will be loaded multile times right? And if we will have 10 files of size 1MB to require in multiple files?

I would like to require those files in mainApp.js, and only once. Then reference it in other files.

To the point, my question:

```
//database
var dbConfig    = require('./dbConfig'),
var db          = dbConfig.db;
//

//routes files
var config = require(modulesPath+'config'),
  achivements = require(modulesPath+'achievements'),
  frontendProcessor = require(modulesPath+'frontendProcessor'),
  encryption = require(modulesPath+'encryption'),
  userOperations = require(modulesPath+'user');
//
```

I would like to use db in other files like:
achievements, frontendProcessor, encryption, userOperations.
There is a bit of code in dbConfig.js. Don't want to require it again in every file like in accepted answer in other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loaded modules are cached, you can find the `require` function source code in [GitHub Joyent/node](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354)

So, the second and later requires of a given module work as references to the first one, you should not find memory issues for that.